# Android Facebook SDK hide login view

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I am building an app that uses the facebook android sdk and sso abilities. Every time you launch my app it will briefly show a facebook window while it logs in via the existing facebook app through sso. Is there a way to hide this screen and make sure my activity stays on top while it's check the facebook credentials and session etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first is user in not logged-in it ask it popup the dialog for login. But once user logged in and you try to send any facebook request, it check the session, if it is valid then it will not shown dialog.

When you login first time store the expire and access token to your shared preferences and on second time pass/set these(expire and access token to the facebook object) and check is Valid session.

Here is brief code;
stored you access token and expires in below method
    facebook.authorize : onComplete listener:

e.g.

```
Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                        editor.putString("access_token",
                                facebook.getAccessToken());
                        editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                facebook.getAccessExpires());
                        editor.commit();
```

for next time by passing these value to facebook object and check its valid ?

```
facebook = new Facebook(MyConstant.Fb_APPID);
            String access_token = preferences.getString("access_token",
                    null);
            long expires = preferences.getLong("access_expires", 0);
            if (access_token != null) {
                facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
            }
            if (expires != 0) {
                facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
            }
if (facebook.isSessionValid()){
                // do your work here
            }
```

hope useful to you....

Comment: I was using the share preferences already but just not implementing it the correct way in my app, thanks!